# Is it possible to custom set query for a WordPress REST API response?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, rest-api

I have a custom post type that I am querying for through WordPress REST API, right now the response returns all the posts. I would like to set the `tax_query` argument based on the user who is sending out the request. Is this possible? Or do I have to create a specifi endpoint for that?

I was thinking something like `pre_get_posts` filter, but I don't know how to do that for the REST API.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` applies to REST API requests too.

Comment: That's what I thought but I still keep getting all posts as if I am logged in as an admin. I'm using JWT Auth plugin to manage the user session where I have to send the user token along with the API request to authenticate the call, however, to get the user authention token I use a customerKey and customerScret created for an admin user along with the non-admin username and password, is that the problem? When I call `get_current_user_id()` within the `pre_get_posts`, whose ID am I getting? I'd think the non-admin user cuz when I request `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me` I do get the non-admin user.

Comment: I created an endpoint to verify whose ID it is that the system is seeing, and yes, it is the non-admin user's ID, which is great! Through this process I am getting more and more familiar with the WordPress REST API and JWT auth, man, it's a lot of fun. As far as my problem goes, it is not solved yet, I'll be doing some more debugging soon.